Nuget restore error - package signature file entry is invalid (field 'compression method' has an invalid value)
Share your knowledge of how to bypass the error NU3005 The package signature file entry is invalid. The central directory header field 'compression method' has an invalid value (8) because no explicit response was found.
I have:

Project on C#
Used docker
Used two sources with nuget package:
api.nuget.org and localregis

Packages that have been downloaded from api.nuget.org, also was uploaded in localregistry (I was thinking as a backup storage space for the used packages).
Project have dockerfile with command - dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org -s https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/149/packages/nuget/index.json name_project
After complete get error, and only this command in docker (if local restore error not found):
error NU3005: Warning As Error: Package 'System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.5.0' from source 'https://gitlab.myorg.com/api/v4/projects/149/packages/nuget/index.json': The package signature file entry is invalid. The central directory header field 'compression method' has an invalid value (8)
I do not get this message when this package used for local builds success.
Some questions:
Why dotnet restore when localregistry and error detection is checked there does not return to the attempt to download the package from another source, for example here api.nuget.org?
Can you somehow make your storage package and periodically update them ?
UPD.
How workaround I removed from localregistry all packages previously downloaded from api.nuget.org and the error is missing.

This looks like a warning being treated as an error on your docker box, but it's not doing that when you're running it locally - do you see a warning in your output when you run the restore locally? Also, can you access the index.json referenced in the error?

Thank you. Right, it does look like a docker setup, but I didn’t set  for any of that stuff. When i restore locally (from cli) i haven't warning, everything is restored successfully.
And there is access to the index.json from the docker container.

Looks like a similar issue here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7414#issuecomment-472561481
Suggests adding <DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder>true</DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder> into your csproj.

It didn’t help, got the same error
